# ExpandableListAdapter vs BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, baseadapter

What is the difference between ExpandableListAdapter and BaseExpandableListAdapter beside the difference one is being interface and other one is abstract method?

Please give examples for each one about on which it should be used.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. ExpandableListAdapter:
>
> ExpandableListAdapter is an Adapter that links a ExpandableListView
>   with the underlying data. The implementation of this interface will
>   provide the data for the children and also initiate the views for the
>   children and groups.  For customization of list we need to implement
>   ExpandableListAdapter in our custom adapter.
>
> 2. BaseExpandableListAdapter:
>
> BaseExpandableListAdapter is a base class for the expandable list
>   adapter used to provide data and Views from some data to
>   ExpandableListView. For Creating a custom ExpandableListView we need
>   to create a custom class and then extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
>   class in that class.

[Reference](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/expandablelistview) - this has examples also and hope this helps